# Как можно вывести связанный список используя __str__ без дополнительных классов?

Tags: python

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next


class List:
    head = None
    tail = None

    def print_list(self):
        a = self.head
        while a is not None:
            print(a.data)
            a = a.next

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node


p = List()
p.append(15)
p.append(25)
p.print_list()
```

Comment: не очень понятен вопрос. ну, переименуйте `print_list` в `__str__`. Или о чем вы спрашиваете?

Comment: @splash58, так он же выводит строку, а не возвращает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Независимо от MaxU уважаемого я набросал тоже класс, но добавил возможность итерироваться по классу и использовал это при печати оного (подсмотрев только стрелку в качестве разделителя у MaxU):

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class List:
    head = None
    tail = None

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node

    def __iter__(self):
        a = self.head
        while a is not None:
            yield a
            a = a.next

    def __str__(self):
        return ' -> '.join(map(str,self))

p = List()
p.append(5)
p.append(15)
p.append(25)
print(p)
```

Вывод:

```
5 -> 15 -> 25
```

Comment: хорошая идея с `__iter__()`! У меня тоже была идея использовать `" -> ".join(...)` но я поленился довести это до конца)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class List:
    head = None
    tail = None

    def __str__(self):
        a = self.head
        res = ""
        while a is not None:
            res += (" -> " if res else "") + str(a)
            a = a.next
        return res

    def print_list(self):
        a = self.head
        while a is not None:
            print(a.data)
            a = a.next

    def append(self, data):
        node = Node(data, None)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = self.tail = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node

p = List()
p.append(15)
p.append(25)
#p.print_list()
print(p)
```

выведет

```
15 -> 25
```